# TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable (using lambda)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[image]

[image]

```
 nb_products_per_basket['order_canceled'] =            
 nb_products_per_basket['InvoiceNo'].apply(lambda x:int('C' in x))
```

I have this :

```
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

**how can I fix it ?**

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: What `nb_products_per_basket['InvoiceNo']` contains? Provide an example, please

Comment: I update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem one, multiple or all values are integers in column `InvoiceNo`.

Possible solution if mixed column values (`C` are in another values not shown in sample data) is cast it to `string`s by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
nb_products_per_basket['order_canceled'] =            
nb_products_per_basket['InvoiceNo'].astype(str).apply(lambda x:int('C' in x))
```

Another solution with [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
nb_products_per_basket['order_canceled'] =            
nb_products_per_basket['InvoiceNo'].str.contains('C', na=False).astype(int)
```

---

If all values are integers there are no `C`, so always get `0`.